# Making POST application/json request with file_get_contents

Tags: php, json

I made a code in PHP. The code works correctly when I run the command:

```php
$payload = file_get_contents ('request.json');
```

However, I need to create dynamic content for the parameters passed by request.json

I made a routine that generates a string with exactly the same content as in the request.json file. However, when I pass this content to the $payload my function does not work.

```php
$options = array (
  'http' => array (
    'header' => "Content-type: application / json",
    'method' => 'POST',
    'content' => $reqjson,
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create ($options);
$result = file_get_contents ($url, false, $context);
```

Why is that? Isn't the type returned by the "file_get_contents" function a common string? How to fix it?

Comment: "Does not work" is a very broad term. What is the expected result? And what is it that you got instead?

Comment: I agree with you. But no error message appears. But the code does not return the expected result. Returns empty / nothing.

Comment: What does `var_dump($result)` give you? Is it `FALSE` or is it empty string (or other value)?

Comment: Also, please try to do a `var_dump($http_response_header);` right after the `file_get_contents` call. See if the response header give you any hint.

Comment: One more thing, did you really have space in-between `application / json` in your context header?

Comment: Thanks. However, it returns only "bool (false)"

Comment: `bool(false)` means the `file_get_content()` remote request somehow failed. Check `$http_response_header` (as I suggested above) to get more hint from server responses.

Comment: There is no space, it was when I used the translator that generated these spaces. Excuse me.

Comment: Each line of `header` should be ended with a `"\r\n"`. Try to append it to "Content-type: application/json" to see if it improves your result.

Comment: Nice. Now something appears. but I still don't understand the error, the content is exactly the same when I compare it in Notepad ++: array (8) {[0] => string (24) "HTTP / 1.0 400 Bad Request" [1] = > string (80) "x-cloud-trace-context: 49e109ed755dc1686779900826822a35 / 15222775102803278623; o = 0" [2] => string (12) "vary: origin" [3] => string (45) "content-type: application / json; charset = utf-8 "[4] => string (23)" cache-control: no-cache "[5] => string (19)" content-length: 229 "[6] => string (35) "Date: Tue, 08 Dec 2020 20:52:29 GMT" [7] => string (15) "Via: 1.1 google"}
bool (false)

Comment: Now the message has changed, after the / r / n:     array(8) { [0]=> string(24) "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request" [1]=> string(80) "x-cloud-trace-context: 2182fe2fde2c567e9970125a83afd877/13326081652832148965;o=0" [2]=> string(12) "vary: origin" [3]=> string(45) "content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" [4]=> string(23) "cache-control: no-cache" [5]=> string(19) "content-length: 229" [6]=> string(35) "Date: Tue, 08 Dec 2020 20:56:43 GMT" [7]=> string(15) "Via: 1.1 google" }

Comment: Add `'ignore_errors' => true` to your stream context options, then file_get_contents will return the response body even if the status code indicated an error. Check if that contains any more info.

Comment: CBroe, thanks. 
Now a new error information is returned: string (229) "{" name ":" HttpStatusCodeException "," message ":" Error extracting userRequest. innerException: JSON5: invalid character '\\ n' at 5: 0 "," stack ": [" no stack or extra properties unless envLevel = DEV | TEST, or logLevel = DEBUG | TRACE "]}"

Comment: @fadsoft: Can you show us the content of `$reqjson` (i.e. the content of `request.json`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, each line of header must end with "\r\n". Please append that to the "Content-Type" line. Second, if the function `file_get_contents()` returns `false`, it mean the request somehow failed. You should examine `$http_response_header` for more information:

```php
$options = array(
  'http' => array(
    'header' => "Content-type: application/json\r\n",
    'method' => 'POST',
    'content' => $reqjson,
  ),
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
if (($result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context)) === false) {
  var_dump($http_response_header);
}
```

If the response header (`$http_response_header`) starts with `HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request`, it means that the server somehow think your request is malformatted. Then,

1. If you have access to the requested server, try to find relevant log file(s) for more information.
2. If you have documentations to the requested server / service, please check carefully the accepted request format.
3. Often request format errors can be:

   - "appliation/json" is not an accepted request format; or
   - The content of `$reqjson` is malformat (e.g. it is supposed to be JSON text, not PHP array).
4. If you're using 3rd party service and still cannot figure out why it doesn't give you the expected result, seek help from the service provider.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Koala Yeung.

As I said, the problem is that I tried to assemble in a string exactly the same content that is inside the request.json file. However, when I use the file_get_contents function to get the contents of the json file, it works. When it is directly in the string variable, the error occurs:

array (8) {[0] => string (24) "HTTP / 1.0 400 Bad Request" [1] => string (79) "x-cloud-trace-context: db4d34cce75495db89a04731bb718b49 / 1272894976542815412; o = 0" [2 ] => string (12) "vary: origin" [3] => string (45) "content-type: application / json; charset = utf-8" [4] => string (23) "cache-control: no-cache "[5] => string (19)" content-length: 229 "[6] => string (35)" Date: Tue, 08 Dec 2020 21:01:45 GMT "[7] => string (15) "Via: 1.1 google"}

bool (false)

I believe it is something related to this type of error:
"The content of $ reqjson is malformat (e.g. it is supposed to be JSON text, not PHP array)."

But the string is identical.